# Shortcode function executed twice?

Tags: shortcode, callbacks

I use a shortcode function to do some processing as a callback from external service. I created a page, the only content of which is the shortcode. User is redirected to this page from external function to trigger some data processing and inform user about the result.

The problem is: the page shows an error, because the specified data have already been processed. Further investigation revealed that the processing function is called twice on a single request.

Is it normal that shortcode function is executed multiple times, even if there is only one occurence of the shortcode on the page? What is a better way of using a plugin to provide a callback point to an external service?

UPDATE: Adding code:

plugin main file:

```
add_shortcode('myplugin-callback-page', 'myplugin_do_callback_page');
function myplugin_do_callback_page () {
    ob_start();
    require "callback_page.php";
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

callback_page.php:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['param1']) || !isset($_GET['param2']) || !isset($_GET['param3'])) {
    // Not a valid callback, redirect to homepage
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
}

echo '<article id="callback-page-container">';

if ($_GET['RESULT'] != "OK") {
        $error = "error from external service";
} else {
        $result = myplugin_api_process_data($_GET['param1']);
        if ($result) {
                // Processed successfully
                do_something();
        } else {
                $error = "error from internal api";
        }
}

// Just display some stuff for user
require 'callback-page-content.php';
?>
</article>
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't execute multiple times for a single occurrence. There must be something in the CODE. Please edit your question and include the CODE, otherwise it's not possible to say anything definitively.

Comment: As I've just commented on an answer: as a simple workaround and something worth doing anyway I'd suggest you cache the result of myplugin_api_process_data in a short-lived transient / the object cache / the user meta so that even if this does get called twice or the page reloaded you only need to call the API once. Or if you want to debug this then try logging the stack trace every time the shortcode is called.